# OnJoinedRoom Not Being Called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

When the player joins the room, I want to assign them a certain role based on the HashTable.
Yet it seems that `OnJoinedRoom` is not even being called as the `Debug.Log` call doesn't appear.

I have checked that I am using `MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks`. I am using Unity (2019.1.0f2 personal) and PUN 2

```
public class GameHandler : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public readonly string[] ROLES = {
        "Villager",
        "Werewolf",
        "Seer",
        "Werewolf",
        "Doctor",
        "Villager"
    };

    Hashtable PlayerProperties = new Hashtable
    {
        {"Role", null}, 
        {"Team", null}
    };

    public TMP_Text ROLE_TXT;

    private void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(PlayerProperties);
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnJoinedRoomCalled");
        GetRoleAndTeam();
    }

    private void GetRoleAndTeam()
    {
        PlayerProperties["Role"] = ROLES[PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount - 1];

        PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(PlayerProperties);        

        string MyRole = (string) PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.CustomProperties["Role"];

        Debug.Log("My Role :");

        ROLE_TXT.text = MyRole;

        if (MyRole.Equals("Werewolf"))
        {
            PlayerProperties["Team"] = "Werewolves";

            PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(PlayerProperties); 
        }

        else
        {
            PlayerProperties["Team"] = "Villagers";

            PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(PlayerProperties);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect it to call `OnJoinedRoom` which therefore runs the `Debug.Log(…)` and also GetRoleAndTeam(), but `OnJoinedRoom` is not being called.

Comment: Are you sure they are actually joining the room? How do you know?

Comment: Oh, that might be the problem, when a player creates a room, do they join it to? All the functions in PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom work fine and PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount returns 1 when only i am in the room.

Comment: Are other PUN callbacks being called such as `OnConnectedToMaster`?

Comment: Other callbacks such as OnConnectedToMaster, OnCreateRoom and OnJoinedLobby all work fine

Comment: A player who creates a room, joins it so both callbacks (`OnCreateRoom` and `OnJoinedRoom`) should be called. The code is missing or you join the room from another script? how do you join the room? Add a log to `Start` to see if `GameHandler` is enabled and active.

Comment: The room creating/joining is handled from another script, and the GameHandler script is both enabled and active. Currently I am joining the room by creating it but it still wont work.

This is how I create a room:

```C#
private void CreateRoomIfConnected(string roomName)
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.IsConnectedAndReady)
        {
            Debug.Log("Creating Room...");
            PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, RoomOptions);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = false;
```

When you use Automatically Sync Scene, the player who connects to the already created room immediately starts loading the scene that the Master has and skip OnJoinedRoom callback.